# update value of a datacolumn in a datable

Tags: datatable, dataset

I have a datatable with data as below;

PID       TName        RName       NameID     PStatus      Status

1           AA          AA                       1

2           BB          DE                       0

Now I want to update the datacolumns  "NameID" and "Status" for all the rows based on some conditions.

To update NameID:- If columns TName and RName are same, the column NameID should be updated as "Success" else "Failure"

To update Status:- If column "PStatus" has value 1, then Status column should be updated as "yes", and "No" for value 0

So, the after updations, the datatable should be like below:

PID       TName        RName       NameID     PStatus      Status

1           AA          AA         Success       1           Yes

2           BB          DE         Failure       0           No

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
update TableName
set NameID=case 
when TName==RName then 'Success'
else 'Failure';

update TableName
set Status=case`enter code here`
when PStatus==1 then 'yes'
else 'no';
```

Comment: I have to do this in C# using LINQ query